# PHP convert link question

Tags: php

How can I convert the following link below using PHP $_SERVER or something similar?

```
'../members/' . urlencode($user_id) . '/images/thumbs/' . $avatar;
```

Comment: Get which URL from where? At which point? I don't understand.

Comment: Second Pekka's notion, we need more information.

Comment: I meant to say the image link.

Comment: @Ghommey no not echo i want to convert the link

Comment: there is no link. convert to what? and what does `$_SERVER` have to do with it?

Comment: @seti - we need to know more clearly what data you have, and what you're desired output/outcome is.

Comment: This question is awfully, awfully unclear. Please try to ask more conscise and detailed questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but I think this may be what you are looking for.

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

This will give you everything in the url after the domain name.

Eg: If you request http://domain.com/sites/test/one.html

This will return /sites/test/one.html

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want a complete URL:

```
$myUrl = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/members/' . urlencode($user_id) . '/images/thumbs/' . $avatar;

echo "<a href='" . $myUrl . "'>" . $myUrl . "</a>";
```